# hql request with different tables

Tags: java, jquery, hibernate, hql

I want to write a complex hql query with relationships from 3 tables. It is necessary to make a selection of the selected columns so that they are located by ID

```
@Query("SELECT p.regId, p.method, p.tax, p.fee, p.netAmount, r.countSec, p.status " +
    "FROM P p INNER JOIN R r INNER JOIN D d on p.regId = r.id AND p.regId = d.id")
List<P> findAllByRegId(String regId);
```

My compiler cannot execute the request, I don't understand what the problem is! Help, please

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "join"
```

Comment: and the compiler does not tell you anything?

Comment: @ScaryWombat org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "join"

Comment: @ScaryWombat 
How about adding filtering by regId, because now I get back the entire table where there is a relationship with regId ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format for multiple joins is

```
SELECT columns ...
FROM table1 AS t1
   INNER JOIN
   table2 AS t2
   ON t1.id = t2.id
   INNER JOIN
   table3 AS t3
   ON t3.id = t1.id
```

Comment: Your version works too! Thanks, it worked, but most likely I'll come back if more complex queries don't work

Answer (score 1):

Your join is totally wrong. You have to add `ON` keyword and map primary key and foreign key in first inner join.

Here is your join, which is wrong

```
SELECT columns FROM A a
INNER JOIN B b
INNER JOIN C c ON a.ColName = b.ColName AND a.ColName = c.ColName
```

Here is the correct syntex for multiple join

```
SELECT columns FROM A a
INNER JOIN B b ON a.ColName = b.ColName
INNER JOIN C c ON a.ColName = c.ColName
```

Here down is modified query

```
@Query("SELECT p.regId, p.method, p.tax, p.fee, p.netAmount, r.countSec, p.status " +
    "FROM P p INNER JOIN R r ON p.regId = r.id INNER JOIN D d ON p.regId = d.id")
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked, but most likely I'll come back if more complex queries don't work))

Comment: What about adding filtering by regId? What i should add in my query?

Comment: You can use Order By https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/mysql_orderby.asp#:~:text=The%20MySQL%20ORDER%20BY%20Keyword,order%2C%20use%20the%20DESC%20keyword.

Comment: also we can add WHERE param and we will get predicate byNeedParam, thank you so much